# Is Hbase a columnar DB

Tags: hbase

Hbase table is based on a column family, this means that each column is a tuple
Each column is stored together

Does this means that HBase is not a columnar DB?
Columnar DB are efficient in IO they can do better compression , since data of a single column tends to be similar.
so it easier to compress one column at a time then to compress the entire table at once

Does the fact that HBase column family is stored together, does it make it less efficient, or does HBase do some clever trick to maintain columnar nature ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HBase is column oriented in the way it stores data  so that column families are stored together (though a table is still sharded to region ). It is columnar like Cassandra but it is not columnar in the Relational DB sense (i.e. it isn't columnar like Vertica) - it is more like a distributed hashmap

You can check out [HBase in Practice](https://www.slideshare.net/larsgeorge/hbase-in-practice) presentation by Lars George which provides an excellent overview of HBase's structure

Comment: I am getting confused lately by the definition of columnar, in other posts, I have discovered that Cassandra is mistakenly classified as columnar but it's not. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447422/6145828

Comment: there are two categories of columnar - see the diagram here https://arnon.me/2012/11/nosql-landscape-diagrams/

Comment: The diagrams are no longer loading :(

Comment: Infochimp removed theirs - mine is still loading :)  (scroll down)