Why can HBase perform fast point queries while ClickHouse is not suitable
Based on the reason that "The key reason why point queries are expensive in ClickHouse is its sparse primary index of main MergeTree table engine family", ClickHouse is not good at point queries. However, HBase also uses LSM as the underlying implementation, but it is good at point queries. Why is this the case? I hope to get an explanation of this problem from the principles.

From the data structure's point of view, HBase uses pure lsm-tree, while ClickHouse organizes data parts into sth similar to lsm-tree, (there is no concept of levels in CH). But note that each part (or SST table in HBase) in CH are separated stored for each column, to optimize for batch reading.

Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't seem clear why point queries are a strength of HBase and a weakness of Clickhouse. HBase also uses columnar storage.

The so called "columnar" of HBase is different from OLAP systems' or at least for different purpose. You can check this URL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379117/is-hbase-a-columnar-db) or even RockDB's column family code. Storage is the first step, further optimization such as vectorization makes OLAP and OLTP system quite different.

This URL (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/faq/use-cases/key-value) mentions that ClickHouse is not suitable for point queries because it uses sparse indexes, is it safe to assume that the argument only applies to ClickHouse in comparison to other B+ tree databases, and in response to my question, it's because it doesn't use the same columnar storage as HBase
