# is it possible to store a column value only once in the column store?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, parquet

I'm new to Cassandra and I have a basic question on how Cassandra and parquet deals this columnar case.
I tried to figure it out by myself but no luck so far. I have found the below info on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)

```
…;Smith:001;Jones:002,004;Johnson:003;…
```

> As two of the records store the same value, "Jones", it is possible to
>   store this only once in the column store, along with pointers to all
>   of the rows that match it. For many common searches, like "find all
>   the people with the last name Jones", the answer is retrieved in a
>   single operation. Other operations, like counting the number of
>   matching records or performing math over a set of data, can be greatly
>   improved through this organization.

My question is that ***"is the above point relevant to Cassandra and Parquet?"***.

```
002,Jones,Mary,50000;
004,Jones,Bob,55000;
```

Does Cassandra/Parquet stores 'Jones' only once or it does store 'Jones' as it receives? Kindly enlightenment me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Cassandra a column oriented or columnar database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441921/is-cassandra-a-column-oriented-or-columnar-database)

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is a wide row store database.
The data stored is differentiated on the basis of partition key and clustering columns.
So for your above use case ,assuming the db modelling is such that **name** (a column) is a **partition key** and **values** (another column) is the **clustering** column.
Clustering column makes the values unique for that column if the partition key is same.
Now the data would be stored internally some thing like this

```
jones |002|004|005... and so on
```

So you can observe that jones is stored *once* while the values (which is the clustering column)are appended as a part of that same row ,hence the name **wide row store** .

Comment: @BDR if it has worked for you please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks