# Why Cassandra not support aggregation internally?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, aggregate

Considering this sentence in many books and articles:

In a columnar architecture, queries that seek to aggregate the values of specific columns are optimized, because of all of the values to be aggregated exist within the same disk blocks. And Cassandra is column family NoSQL database.

[image: NoSL]

If this sentence is true, why Cassandra does not support aggregation functions internally? Or I've misunderstood this sentence or concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why Cassandra does not support aggregation functions internally

Cassandra does support per request aggregation functions (both custom in java, python, javascript and some premade ones) that when used on a single partition works within limits. Keeping in mind that this queries are really designed to be answered in a few milliseconds though so something that calculates the mean of a million values will not function well if queried often.

Aggregations cannot easily be kept up to date as deletes (particularly hard in distributed environment since the delete may not even be seen on all nodes yet - remember that Cassandra is AP not CP) and ttl'd data expires so the entire set to aggregate must be re calculated and sent from the consistency level amount of replicas to the coordinator to calculate. So while the data of a partition is kept sequentially on disk across some number of sstables and can be merged pretty efficiently it can still be expensive on the coordinator, and if done across a range the amount of data transferred around and calculated can end up failing (timing out) easily.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is a row-storage engine. If you want to get all the records that match a specific column value, you need to do a full scan of the table.

See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441921/is-cassandra-a-column-oriented-or-columnar-database).