# Is Cassandra suitable for Aggregate Queries?

Tags: database, cassandra, aggregate

I have read that Columnar databases are apt for Aggregate Queries and Cassandra is a columnar database. I am trying to use count( values 'between' or '>=' for a specific partition) in Cassandra. Is this performance intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common misconception that Cassandra is a columnar database. I think it comes from the old terminology "column family" for tables. Data is stored in rows containing columns of key-value pairs which is why the tables used to be called column families.

A major difference compared to traditional relational databases is that Cassandra tables can be 2-dimensional (each record contains exactly one row) or multi-dimensional (each record can contain ONE OR MORE rows).

On the other hand, columnar databases flips a 2-dimensional table such that data is stored in columns instead of rows, specifically optimised for analytics-type queries such as aggregations -- this is NOT Cassandra.

Going back to your question, counting the rows within a single partition is ok to do for most data models. The key is to restrict the query to just one partition like:

```
    SELECT COUNT(some_column) FROM table_name
        WHERE pk = ?
```

It's also OK to count the rows in a range query as long as they're restricted to one partition like:

```
    SELECT COUNT(some_column) FROM table_name
        WHERE pk = ?
        AND clustering_col >= ?
        AND clustering_col <= ?
```

If you don't restrict the query to a single partition, it might work for (a) very small datasets and (b) clusters with a very low number of nodes but it doesn't scale as (c) the dataset grows, and (d) the number of nodes increases. I've explained why performing aggregates such as `COUNT()` is bad in Cassandra in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6897/.

This is not to say that Cassandra isn't a good fit. Cassandra is a good choice if your primary use case is for storing real-time data for OLTP workloads. For analytics queries, you just need to use other software like Apache Spark since the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) will optimise the queries to Cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Cassandra is a partitioned row store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441921/is-cassandra-a-column-oriented-or-columnar-database/25447422#25447422).  Data is stored in partitions, clustered together and served as "rows."  It is *not* a columnar database.

An aggregate query to run a count will not perform well on Cassandra.  To attempt it *will* be performance intensive, right up until the coordinator node times-out the query.

If this is a use case you need to solve for, another database will be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @aaron's response, if you're performing an aggregate operation *just* within your partition, that might be okay. For example,

Let's assume your table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace_name.table_name (
 partition_key1 some_type,
 partition_key2 some_type,
 clustering_key1 some_type,
 clustering_key2 some_other_type,
 regular_column1 some_type,
 ...
 regular_columnN some_type,
 PRIMARY KEY ((partition_key1, partition_key2), clustering_key1, clustering_key2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(ck1 DESC, ck2 DESC)
AND ...;
```

it may be okay to do [aggregation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlAggregates.html) queries such as the following to be performant,

```
SELECT COUNT(some_regular_column) FROM keyspace_name.table_name WHERE partition_key1 = ? AND partition_key2 = ? AND clustering_key1 >= ? AND clustering_key2 <= ?;
```